# Make this directory sync script detect change and run in the background

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this simple python script which will synchronize the contents of `sourcedir` folder to `targetdir` folder.

Here is the code;

```
from dirsync import sync

sourcedir = "C:/sourcedir"
targetdir ="C:/targetdir"
sync(sourcedir, targetdir, "sync")
```

It is cumbersome to manually run this script whenever changes are made. I would like to have this script running in the background so that whenever there is any change in `sourcedir` folder, `targetdir` folder will be synchronized automatically.

I am using python v3.5

Comment: you can create a cron job which can run your script frequently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's <strike>an app</strike> [a library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) for that:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer


def event_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = '/tmp/fun'
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're running your script on linux, you can use [inotify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify). ([GitHub](https://github.com/dsoprea/PyInotify)).

It uses a kernel feature that notifies an event when something happens in a watched directory, as file modification, access, creation, etc. This has very little overhead, as it's using `epoll` system call to watch for changes.

```
import inotify.adapters

i = inotify.adapters.Inotify()
i.add_watch(b'/tmp')
try:
    for event in i.event_gen():
        if event is not None:
            (header, type_names, watch_path, filename) = event
            if 'IN_MODIFY' in type_names:
                # Do something
                sync(sourcedir, targetdir, "sync")
finally:
    i.remove_watch(b'/tmp')
```

Also, it's recommended to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) to execute the `sync` part, unless the script will not watch for changes during the sync process. Depending on your `sync` implementation, this could lead to process synchronization problems, a huge topic to discuss here.

My advice, try the easy approach, running everything on the same process and test if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, you have [watcher](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watcher), a Python port of the .NET FileSystemWatcher API.

And for Linux, [inotifyx](https://launchpad.net/inotifyx) which is a simple Python binding to the Linux inotify file system event monitoring API.

Answer (score 2):

I think this two links should get you started:

[Python WMI example](http://wmiplanet.blogspot.no/2011/07/python-wmi-example-using_05.html)

[VBScript Filesystemwatcher example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/445f54d2-3b0c-4984-86e0-22f5734b368a/vbscript-wmi-filesystemwatcher?forum=ITCG)

The basic idea is to query the WMI and get notified to changes in a folder/file.

Answer (score 2):

You could check for the modification time (e.g., with `os.path.getmtime(sourcepath)`) of the source dir and only synchronize if it changed.

```
import os
import time
from dirsync import sync

sourcedir = "C:/sourcedir"
targetdir ="C:/targetdir"

mtime, oldmtime = None, None

while True:
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(sourcedir)
    if mtime != oldmtime:
        sync(sourcedir, targetdir, "sync")
        oldmtime = mtime
    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use FindFirstChangeNotification function of win32 api.

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Answer (score 1):

You may use [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/), a recently updated python utility to monitor file system events.

This code from documentation:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```